# Traverse passed React element and add additional props to a deeply nested child

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

First of all, what I'm trying to do feels a bit wrong, but it seems a simpler solution compared to checking and fixing all the use cases.

The structure in the project is something like (very simplified for this question):

SomeComponent.jsx:

```
<div>
  <Modal header={<SomeModalHeader />}>
     content to show in the modal
  </Modal>
</div>
```

Modal.jsx:

```
<div>
  <div className="header">
    {header}
  </div>
  <div className="content">
    {children}
  </div>
</div>
```

SomeModalHeader.jsx:

```
<div>
  <Link to="/page-1">Link 1</Link>
  <Link to="/page-2">Link 2</Link>
  <Link to="/page-3">Link 3</Link>
</div>

// ...

return connect(...)(SomeModalHeader)
```

*The `Link` component is imported from `react-router-dom`. The whole component is enhanced by `connect` from `react-redux`.*

What I would like to do is handle the navigation away from the `Modal` by first displaying a warning message to the user that their changes will be lost and if they confirm, close the modal and proceed with the navigation. I can't rely on the location change since the `Link` could point to the same page since opening a modal doesn't change the browser's url. I planned to do this by adding an `onClick` handler inside `Modal` for all `Link` components inside the passed `header` component. The equivalent of this with the regular DOM API would be (with jQuery, for simplicity of this example): `$(header).find('.link').click(handlerFn)`. But I am fully aware that this should not be done in React, so I'm looking for "the React way".

The problem is that there are multiple different `header` components and there might be even more in the future, so I'd like for this to be a more generic solution, not modify each of the header components.

And another problem is that I haven't found a way to get children components of `header` because the `connect` wraps it into its own component and then I can't get the reference to the wrapped component. I tried with passing [`{withRef: true}`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments-1) to `connect` function, but I still haven't found the [`getWrappedInstance`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#getwrappedinstance-reactcomponent) on the `header` component.

Is there a way to accomplish this without adding changes to the modal header components?

Comment: Ideally, your `<Link/>`s should be in an array that you can `map()` through and then you only have to add your callback with `onClick={}` once. Why are you trying to get the child components? Remember you're not working with a DOM interaction library but rather you're creating a UI using JS and JSX syntax. Use state and callbacks to modify the DOM.

Comment: How links are defined doesn't change the fact that these components are tucked away in a component which is passed as prop to the component where I want to add the onClick handler. The links form a breadcrumb view inside the modal and I want to display a warning that changes will be lost when the link is clicked, before closing the modal and navigating away. But sometimes the link points to the same page so I can't rely on location change. I know react isn't DOM interaction library, I've mentioned this in the question already.

Comment: i think it would be best if you dont pass the header prop as a component, then render it as a component inside the modal with extra prop to point to your onClick handler and from that prop pass it to your links

Comment: @ReiDien the whole idea is to avoid looking for and updating all the occurrences of Modal usage. If I go and do that I might as well do it properly and attach the `onClick` event handler to each of the `Link` components which are then used inside `header`.